# CGPDFDocumentRelease() crashes app, wrongly says already deallocated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I am writing a PDF viewer for iOS. I obtain a reference to the pdf when I initialize my viewcontroller like,

```
pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
```

Then I use it throughout the life of that class to obtain CGPDFPageRef's like,

```
CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, docPage);
```

The child view controllers use these pages and release them when dealloc'd. However, when I attempt to release the pdf itself (with CGPDFDocumentRelease), I get the following error:

```
[Not A Type release]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

What is up with that? It wouldn't be a problem, but my heapshot analysis is packed with CG objects and a massive  allocation that all seems to correlate with the pdf (individual pages) content stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must not release `pageRef` if you did not retain it. Even if you retained it, it might not be usable if the document itself was deallocated. So you might need to retain both the page and the document in your child view controllers, and release them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've used your approach. The problem that I was asking about has to do with the fact that all pagerefs to the same page will share a memory address.